# Is it possible to have a Spark DataFrame partitioned by multiple columns, and at the same time partitioned by all the individual columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

To get more efficient joins in pyspark, I would like to repartition my dataframes on multiple columns at the same time.

This is not what the `repartition` function already does. For example, if I am partitioning on columns 'c1' and 'c2', the `reparition` function only ensures that all rows with the pairs of values `(c1, c2)` fall in the same partition. Instead, I would like to have a partitioning that ensures that that all rows with the same value of `c1` fall on the same parition, and the same for `c2`.

With this, I would like to optimize my pipeline when doing a join on `c1` and then another join on `c2`, without having to reparition (implicitly or explicitely) 2 times.

Is it possible to achieve this?